# Can loops be created with dplyr(tally) and ggplot (bar)?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I want to look at answers from a closed answer survey (100+ questions). Supervisor suggested graphing each Q to quickly look over.

To graph one question I have completed the following:

```
out <- farmer %>% group_by(Device.Name) %>% tally %>% mutate(freq = n/sum(n)*100) %>% print
ggplot(out, aes(Device.Name, freq)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") + ggtitle("Device.Name")
ggsave("out.jpg")
```

What I would like to do is run this for each column without having to write the code 100 times. Can I loop this to complete?

Comment: Hi Williams can you share the data you have? Not all the details. Maybe name conventions, characteristics, features, etc. Any useful patterns for manipulation and automation.

Comment: If you tidy your data into long form (so you're working with groups within one column rather than multiple columns), then `dplyr::do` will mean you don't need loops.